# Why Trump's ban includes Iran and Iraq, but not Saudi Arabia?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

[Here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14906/is-there-an-officially-stated-reason-why-trumps-ban-includes-iran-and-iraq-but/14911#14911) `there is a question with two answers which are irrelevant since OP wants "officially stated" reasons. I ask the same question without the "officially stated" phrase to migrate answers here:`

---

A 90-day suspension on anyone arriving from Iraq, Syria, Iran, Libya, Somalia, Sudan, and Yemen, except certain visa categories such as diplomats.

> Why these countries were selected?

It is somehow strange. Note that Saudi Arabia (supporting Wahhabism) is origin of terrorist groups like Al-Qaeda (and Daesh,...). The most suspects of 9/11 have Saudi nationality, while (some) countries in the list are not responsible for any terrorist attack inside the US.

Comment: so, instead of editing the other question, you are posting a new, almost identical one?

Comment: Yes,  I changed world, instead of changing myself :)

Comment: If you believe the answers to the other question are lacking, downvote them. Posting an identical question does not make any sense. Also, questions inviting speculative answers are off topic.

Comment: @yannis this is not duplicate

Answer (score -1):

1. Economic reasons:

   - Saudi-Arabia has a lot of control over the global oil market.
   - US supplies Saudi-Arabia with weapons. Big trade: creating jobs, and Preserving the value of $.
2. Political reasons:

   - Common enemy: Iran and its allies in the region.
   - Common friend: Saudi Arabia has a friendly relationship with Israel (e.g. see [here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2016/04/13/how-two-red-sea-islands-shed-light-on-secret-relations-between-israel-and-saudi-arabia/?utm_term=.9c783d52f811).)

Comment: You might want to note that the EO doesn't list the countries; rather, it refers to the list of countries that are singled out for special treatment in connection with the Visa Waiver Program.  So the list of countries was actually developed before the current president took office.